# How to override third party style classes in Next.js using React Flow?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, react-flow

Unable to override third party style classes in NextJS.
I am using react flow library and trying to update the classes using index.css but css is not getting load in browser.

I should be able to override the classes, trying to integrate react flow in my application.

```
[index.module.css: ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiWyF.png)
[component screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzrfQ.png)
[component screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL4za.png)
[folderStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRBgU.png)
```

Comment: It looks like you writing global styles, trying to import them as global styles, but using module-scoped css file. Next.js docs provide good overview of how to use css stylesheets in Next.js app - https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/styling/css-modules